# Cannot find folders / files after mv on ubuntu

Tags: mv

Having cd /poolf/sharef I have a folder named media.

I issued the command sudo mv -T media Media

The folder renamed media to Media as expected but the contents have disappeared.

Can someone tell me how to recover them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation for `mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/mv.1.html), I think you may have meant `-t` rather than `-T`:

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
        move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY

-T, --no-target-directory
        treat DEST as a normal file
```

The simplest way to recover your files would be to restore from backup. Aside from this, you *may* be able to recover some of the data [via `testdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/testdisk.8.html), but you will want to first shut your machine down (so that no more data is written to the disk) and use a bootable USB stick. Do note that depending on whether you are using an SSD or HDD, and how much data has been written since the operation, you may not be able to recover all of the files.

Comment: I’m not clear what `treat DEST as a normal file` means. Sounds like what ever is being moved gets turned into a file. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yep. You're right. Using `-T` means "treat the object as a file". As it was a directory, this would have been a destructive change.

Comment: I do not believe the `-T` option would do such damage. That rename command is probably not what caused the files to disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I will restore from backup.